# Adding Rails location to coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, google-places-api

I have the following Coffeescript code that I would like to add the users current latitude and longitude to:

```
initLocationField = ->
  addListing.locationField.autocomplete
    messages:
      noResults: '',
      results: ->
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/locations"
        data:
          term: request.term
          size_type: "local"
          include_google_places: true
          radius: 30000
        success: (data) ->
          response data
```

In my app, the way I access a users location is by

```
User.location.lat_long
```

or

```
current_user.location.lat_long
```

pretty strait forward.  My question is if I want to add this piece of information to the data: parameters, how would I add this in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.erb` extension to your coffee file, and then, you can use `erb` syntax in your CoffeeScript. Make sure that the asset pipeline is active, which is the default.

```
    data:
      term: request.term
      size_type: "local"
      include_google_places: true
      radius: 30000
      lat_long: <%= current_user.location.lat_long %>
```